# How to test an unreleased version of the app using branch.io?

Tags: branch.io

So i want to test an unreleased version of the app for deferred deep links. How do i do it? As the changes made will not be there in the app i download from the play store after redirecting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alex from Branch.io here: this is pretty easy to do! On your [Branch dashboard](https://dashboard.branch.io/#/settings/link) under **Settings -> Link Settings -> Android**, select `Custom URL`, and put in the information requested.

Alternatively, you can delete the app from your phone, open the link, install a side-loaded build of the app (directly from Android Studio), and then manually launch the app. You'll still be deep linked to the correct place.

Comment: @AnujRajput yes indeed it can